# invalid argument jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Webpage error details

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 116
Char: 165
Code: 0
URI: /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2

I've searched everyhwere for answers. I've finally determined that this error is being caused by the php called in this page: http://pittsburghweddingphotographer.whsites.net/wedding-pricing/

This error comes up in IE8 and not Firefox.

The availability script (php code) was given to me by a friend.  I simply replaced my info with his.

Would someone please assist me in working this out?  Feel free to talk down to me, I'm not even a novice.

Comment: I like the security of the right-click suppression... hahah

Comment: Thanks Hunter.  We do what we can to prevent image theft.  LOL

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code in photopro-scripts.js:

```
$(".footer-widgets-1 .widget:last").css({
    borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0 !important', marginBottom: '0 !important'});

$(".footer-widgets-2 .widget:last").css({
    borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0 !important', marginBottom: '0 !important'});

$(".footer-widgets-3 .widget:last").css({
    borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0 !important', marginBottom: '0 !important'});
```

To this:

```
$(".footer-widgets-1 .widget:last").css({
    'border-bottom' : 'none', 'padding-bottom' : '0 !important', 'margin-bottom' : '0 !important'});

$(".footer-widgets-2 .widget:last").css({
    'border-bottom' : 'none', 'padding-bottom' : '0 !important', 'margin-bottom' : '0 !important'});

$(".footer-widgets-3 .widget:last").css({
    'border-bottom' : 'none', 'padding-bottom' : '0 !important', 'margin-bottom' : '0 !important'});
```

When specifying the css properties this way they need to be in quotes and the property names were incorrect.  Here is the jquery api doc link for .css() [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: I'm no jQuery guy, but looking at the code it sure looks like jquery will substitute `paddingBottom` for `padding-bottom` and he'll be right back where he started.

Comment: Well I have actually never seen the .css function used in the way it was originally declared on that script.  Also the javascript error is that of an invalid argument when referencing borderBottom, paddingBottom, and marginBottom.  In the IE8 console I got 6 javascript errors on these properties.  It may translate these to those values internally but I believe it will work this way.

Comment: not sure I understand your recent comments on this post or Hemlock's answer

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't like that you are trying to set `paddingBottom = '0 !important';` Take off the important; it shouldn't be needed since you are setting the padding directly on the element.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it is at line 35 of photopro-scripts.js.

Comment: using !important while not correct css (it is a compatibility hack) wouldn't cause a javascript error

Comment: @antonlavey You shouldn't assume when it comes to IE. Paste this into your IE location bar and witness the error. Remove the !important and the error will go away. `javascript: try { document.body.style.paddingTop = "0 !important"; } catch (e) { alert(e.message) }; void(0);`

Comment: Good point I think jquery takes care of most of these inconsistencies though.

Comment: the theme developer:                                          I was finally able to get the error to throw on a demo install, & the guy @ the forums was right – IE was choking on the margins on the jquery that eliminates a bottom rule on the last item in a footer column.

Comment: lib/js/photopro-scripts.js change this:
                $(".footer-widgets-1 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0', marginBottom: '0'});
                                
                $(".footer-widgets-2 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0', marginBottom: '0'});
                                
                $(".footer-widgets-3 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none', paddingBottom: '0', marginBottom: '0'});

Comment: To this $(".footer-widgets-1 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none'});
                                
                $(".footer-widgets-2 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none'});
                                
                $(".footer-widgets-3 .widget:last").css({
                                borderBottom: 'none'});
 
Save  file & re-upload via FTP. It got rid of the error for me in IE8 on PC windows7                                                     -It did not appear to fix the problem on my end.  :(

Comment: @user557491 (you can assign yourself a username you know) I don't understand your comment. I just visited the site and the code is not changed.